# How to write in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

To write in polar form you use this formula
$$z=a+bi=r \left(\cos \theta+i\sin\theta \right)$$
I want the polarform for this rectangular function$$4\sqrt2(-1+i)$$

See this for more information [Complex number from a region](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370381/complex-number-from-a-region)

Comment: what function? All I see is a point in the complex plane.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: the polar form of $a+ib$ is $|a+ib| e^{\rm{Arg}(a+ib)}$.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood problem correctly, then
$$
-1+i = \sqrt{1+1} \left\{ \cos \left[ \text{atan2}(1,-1)\right] + i\sin \left[ \text{atan2}(1,-1)\right]\right\}
$$
where you can find info about $\text{atan2}(y,x)$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition). So $\theta = -\frac \pi 4 + \pi = \frac {3\pi}4$.

And finally
$$
4 \sqrt 2(-1+i) = 8 \left( \cos \frac {3\pi}4  + i \sin \frac {3\pi}4\right)
$$